# How to map MySQL geometry type in Java using MyBatis?

Tags: java, mysql, geometry, mybatis

How to map MySQL geometry type in java using MyBatis? My database table is like the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `path` geometry DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have no idea to design the POJO and write my mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [locationtech/jts](https://github.com/locationtech/jts)'s Geometry:

MySQL Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `geo` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `path` geometry DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Geometry Entity Class:

```java
package com.xyz.entity;

import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class GeometryEntity implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private Geometry geometry;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", GeometryEntity.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("geometry=" + geometry)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Mapper Class:

```java
package com.xyz.mapper;

import com.xyz.entity.GeometryEntity;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface GeometryMapper {
    int insertGeometry(@Param("entity") GeometryEntity entity);

    List<GeometryEntity> selectAll();

    GeometryEntity selectGeometryById(int id);
}
```

Type Handler Class:

```java
package com.xyz.typehandler;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.PrecisionModel;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.ByteOrderValues;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKBReader;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKBWriter;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class GeometryTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Geometry>  {
    private static final PrecisionModel PRECISION_MODEL = new PrecisionModel(PrecisionModel.FIXED);
    private static final Map<Integer, GeometryFactory> GEOMETRY_FACTORIES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Geometry parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        byte[] bytes = serializeGeometry(parameter);
        ps.setBytes(i, bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public Geometry getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(columnName);
        try {
            return deserializeGeometry(bytes);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Geometry getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(columnIndex);
        try {
            return deserializeGeometry(bytes);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Geometry getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        byte[] bytes = cs.getBytes(columnIndex);
        try {
            return deserializeGeometry(bytes);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Geometry deserializeGeometry(byte[] bytes) throws ParseException {
        if (bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        int srid = buffer.getInt();
        byte[] geometryBytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(geometryBytes);

        // Thread-safe
        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = GEOMETRY_FACTORIES.computeIfAbsent(srid, i -> new GeometryFactory(PRECISION_MODEL, i));

        // WKBReader is not thread-safe. a ThreadLocal variable can be used instead of creating a reader for each call.
        WKBReader reader = new WKBReader(geometryFactory);
        return reader.read(geometryBytes);
    }

    private byte[] serializeGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        int srid = geometry.getSRID();
        byte[] bytes = new WKBWriter(2, ByteOrderValues.LITTLE_ENDIAN).write(geometry);
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length + 4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                .putInt(srid)
                .put(bytes)
                .array();
    }
}
```

Mapper XML Config File (geometry.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.xyz.mapper.GeometryMapper">

    <insert id="insertGeometry" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
        INSERT INTO `geo`
        VALUES (#{entity.id}, #{entity.geometry})
    </insert>

    <select id="selectAll" resultMap="geometryResultMap">
        SELECT *
        FROM `geo`
    </select>

    <select id="selectGeometryById" parameterType="int" resultMap="geometryResultMap">
        SELECT *
        FROM `geo`
        WHERE `id` = #{parameter}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="geometryResultMap" type="com.xyz.entity.GeometryEntity">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="geometry" column="path"/>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

MyBatis XML Config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "https://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="com.xyz.typehandler.GeometryTypeHandler" javaType="org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry" jdbcType="BLOB"/>
    </typeHandlers>
    <!--    <environments> tag goes here -->
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/xyz/mapping/mapping/geometry.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Sample Code:

```java
GeometryMapper geometryMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(GeometryMapper.class);

WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();

// Inserting a point
GeometryEntity pointEntity = new GeometryEntity();
Point point = (Point) wktReader.read("POINT(6 42)");
pointEntity.setId(1);
pointEntity.setGeometry(point);
geometryMapper.insertGeometry(pointEntity);

// Inserting a polygon
GeometryEntity polygonEntity = new GeometryEntity();
Polygon polygon = (Polygon) wktReader.read("POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0),(5 5,7 5,7 7,5 7, 5 5))");
polygonEntity.setId(2);
polygonEntity.setGeometry(polygon);
geometryMapper.insertGeometry(polygonEntity);

// Inserting a collection
GeometryEntity collectionEntity = new GeometryEntity();
GeometryCollection geometryCollection = (GeometryCollection) wktReader.read("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(10 10), POINT(30 30), LINESTRING(15 15, 20 20))");
collectionEntity.setId(3);
collectionEntity.setGeometry(geometryCollection);
geometryMapper.insertGeometry(collectionEntity);

sqlSession.commit();

geometryMapper.selectAll().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
GeometryEntity[id=1, geometry=POINT (6 42)]
GeometryEntity[id=2, geometry=POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0), (5 5, 7 5, 7 7, 5 7, 5 5))]
GeometryEntity[id=3, geometry=GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (10 10), POINT (30 30), LINESTRING (15 15, 20 20))]
```

MySQL:

```sql
SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJson(path) FROM `geo`;
```

| id | ST_AsGeoJson(path) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [6.0, 42.0]} |
| 2 | {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.0], [10.0, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0], [0.0, 10.0], [0.0, 0.0]], [[5.0, 5.0], [7.0, 5.0], [7.0, 7.0], [5.0, 7.0], [5.0, 5.0]]]} |
| 3 | {"type": "GeometryCollection", "geometries": [{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [10.0, 10.0]}, {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [30.0, 30.0]}, {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[15.0, 15.0], [20.0, 20.0]]}]} |